# Stupid question - How do I calculate $\Phi(1.5)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I just can't figure out even what to search when all I have is $\Phi$. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use a z-table...

Comment: Search for tables of the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal variable, or look on-line for a calculator for normal probabilities. There are several of the latter available.

Comment: http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=55 also tables http://classweb.gmu.edu/tkeller/Tables/standard_normal.pdf

Comment: If by $\Phi$ is all you have, you mean that you are limited in your use of technology or tables, you could calculate the Taylor Expansion to a few terms and integrate that- however that sounds like a miserable waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) since $\Phi(z)=\frac12\left(1+\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt2}\right)\right)$.

For example, $\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{1.5}{\sqrt2}\right)$ [is approximately](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erf%281.5%2Fsqrt%282%29%29) $0.866386$ hence $\Phi(1.5)$ [is approximately](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Phi%281.5%29) $0.933193$.